# boostrap navbar-nav at right is not working

Tags: css

Im using bootstrap navbar but its not working as I want. I want a menu with the brand at left and the menu items and form at right. But as you can see in the example: "https://jsfiddle.net/bnrgcupL/" the menu items are appearing next to the  brand. Do you know how to fix this?

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `jquery` and `bootstrap.js` have been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove class `mr-auto` from `<ul class="navbar-nav">` declaration. 
Add `pull-right` class if you feel so, but not really required.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why if the nav its inside a container and row divs dont works properly? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/bnrgcupL/2/.

Comment: I don't get the question in comment clearly. What are row divs you are referring to?

Comment: The ".container" and ".row" divs.

Comment: The container class is not an issue, but row class has display:flex which causes the entire right side menu to come to left side.